# Mesh doesn't follow the armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, rigify

I'm trying to rig this 3D astronaut model, but I'm having problems. The mesh doesn't follow the armature, I tried all the fixing steps. but nothing happens. A strange thing also happens when moving a bone. blender starts to lag for some reason. Can someone help me out?
Here's the link to the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ujtoCIPFT7M03eqsOH_TQPPsYmUkmr5

[image]

Comment: Your mesh is very high poly, I guess you need to work with a lower poly version, you should retopologize it

Comment: I think so... it has like 1.9 million tris

Comment: btw I never did it, do I have to use the QuadriRemesh or Voxel Remesh?

Comment: Now I'm trying the QuadriFlow Remesh and I get this: QuadriFlow: The mesh needs to be manifold and have face normals that point in a consistent direction.

Comment: I don't know a lot about those, you need to create a second object (plane) and begin to snap its vertices on the original mesh, then extrude etc... if your high-poly is too heavy and makes the work too tedious you may consider using this kind of destructive tool, yes

Comment: Now I'm using the decimate modifier and stopping only when the mesh is not looking good

Comment: Ok, I reduced the number of tris from 1,9 million to 390K, without any differences!

Comment: so now you can either try to use the new mesh or retopologize it (which would be better)

Comment: If you can answer this question, like saying reduce the polygon count, so that I can close this thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your mesh is too high in polygons, it will make rigging and animation tedious if not impossible, try to reduce the amount of polygons and, if possible, retopologize it.